# I want to build a docusign api to allow my cutomers who have docusign account to manage them through our website to interact

Tags: docusignapi

I have a small business where 5 of my customers use docusign. They want to be able to manage their docusign accounts through our website. I have created a docusign api on my end which I tested using my own developer account using my integration and secret keys which I store on my server in the db. I now want to allow my 5 customers to use this api to control their own docusing accounts. Do they all need to have a developer account and make it go live? I'm sure there is a better way and I cant make sense of it.
Do I need to push my app to live as well and purchase an API plan from docusign?

Please help it s hard to find any resource about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do they all need to have a developer account and make it go live?

No, they don't need to. They have a production account and once your app [goes live](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/) they can use your app with their account. If you want them to test your app in the developer environment first - then yes, they can get a developer account (which is free) to do some testing, but not required at all.

> Do I need to push my app to live as well and purchase an API plan from
> docusign?

Yes, you need to make your app live so that it can be used by paying customers in production. You would need your own production account to do that. If you are an [ISV/Partner](https://developers.docusign.com/partner/integration-guide/getting-started-isv/) - you can get a free one, otherwise you will have to pay for your plan.

Comment: Thank you. But my app needs an integration and secret key of a docusign account to connect to it. How would my customers get an integration key without having a developer account which then needs to live?

Comment: Also when you say they can use my app I just want to clarify that my app is simply using the PHP SDK of docusign. In order to authenticate with a docusign account I would need their integration and secret key but how would my customers provide me with this info? Should I expect them to purchase an api license plan?

Comment: When you go live, your integration key (IK) is copied to production for use by any customer in production. You can then create a new secret key for it in production.

Comment: the integration key is not per customer, anyone can use it, even if you created it on your account.

Comment: Right thanks. So once my app is in production what info would I need from each of my customers that is unique to their account in order to connect to their docusign account? Like I said I currently use IK and a SECRET KEY to establish a connection.

Comment: accountId and/or userId, that is passed to you after you use Auth Code Grant for authentication.

Comment: baseURI also, which can be different in production for different customers.

Comment: Thank you. Just one last question. Do I need to just purchase an API licence plan from docusign and does an API licence have any limitation about how many different accounts it can connect to?

Comment: There are no limitation, any and all accounts can connect to it.